# Algorithm for distance of a point from a periodic curve

Tags: algorithm

Can anyone suggest an algorithm with low time complexity to find distance of a point from a periodic closed curve with period 1?

I have tried doing Gradient descent method to get the local minimas but it doesn't ensure that it will find all local minimas. How to proceed for this?

Comment: Sounds like this problem has a standard mathematical function description, and you can use the derivative of that to find the minimum. Without seeing the (functional) description of "periodic closed curve with period 1", it'll be hard to determine what that function is though.

Comment: Given
• a simple closed curve C in R
2 given by C : [0, 1] → R
2
such that
C(t) = (X(t), Y (t)), 0 ≤ t ≤ 1,
where X, Y : R → R are infinitely differentiable periodic functions with period 1 (for
instance, the ellipse given by C(t) = (2 cos(2πt), 3 sin(2πt)) is one such curve), and
• a point (x0, y0) ∈ R

find the closest point (xc, yc) on the curve C to x0,y0.

Comment: You have x and y coordinates of the curve as a function of t, and x and y coordinates of the point of interest. Assuming a Pythagorean distance, that seems like a straightforward function, with a derivative for obtaining the extrema.

Comment: I am looking for a method that does it computationally faster.

Comment: Finding the zero points of the derivative should be pretty fast.

Comment: For a point with the same x co-ordinate as the centroid of the curve but with a much larger y co-ordinate this is almost the same as maximising the y co-ordinate on the curve so I don't think the structure of the problem makes this easier or harder than maximising/minimising an arbitrary function of one variable. Any ideas specific to this problem will have to be ideas specific to the curve concerned.